# Creating an AWS Data Pipeline EMR cluster using ShellCommandActivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

When I create an [AWS EMR](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/) I can do so through their simple wizard on the [AWS Management Console](https://aws.amazon.com/console/). Once it's completed I can test it out and when I'm happy with it's configuration I can simply click the AWS CLI Export button and copy the [CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command that creates the EMR.

I need to create an EMR as part of my [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) process and rather than configure the [EmrCluser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emrcluster.html) and then running whatever [EmrActivity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emractivity.html) I want I'm wondering if I could just copy my CLI command I exported during my testing and paste it inside a [ShellCommandActivity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html) which will create the EMR. From there I could use either an EmrActivity to do some processing or just use the ShellCommandActivity to do the processing.

Can I create my AWS Data Pipeline EMR Cluster using a CLI command that's run through a ShellCommandActivity? And if I do so will I be able to run an EmrActivity against that EMR Cluster? I just think it would be easier to create the EMR this way because I can use the AWS Management Console to create my EMR and then I can test my EMR before exporting the CLI command rather than going through the process of properly constructing the EMR through the AWS Data Pipeline wizard/JSON process. I.E., The actual EMR wizard on the AWS Management Console is way easier than the Data Pipeline wizard for creating the EMR on the AWS Management Console, especially when it comes to choosing my security groups and various configurations.

**Update:**

I just verified that I can in fact run a CLI command through the ShellCommandActivity to create my EMR through the Data Pipeline but is this possibly a code smell or bad practice? Are there any downfalls to creating and EMR on the Data Pipeline this way rather than doing it through the predefined EmrCluster command?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but a little complicated:

1. The following action or the script itself would have to wait for the cluster to be created. Make sure the action does not time out.
2. The data pipeline does not know about the cluster, hence you need to specify a `workerGroup` instead of `runsOn` in the EMRActivity. You also need to install [Task Runner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-user-managed.html) on the cluster.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I didn't even think about what I would do for the EMR boot time. Also, I was having trouble figuring out how to get the EMR Cluster ID in order to run tasks on the EMR Cluster. So looks like I'll have to just use the EmrCluster and EmrActivity fields. Thanks.